# How to send multiple emails in one go with SparkPost PHP API?

Tags: php, sparkpost

I've successfully used the PHP transmissions endpoint in Sparkpost PHP API https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost#send-an-email-using-the-transmissions-endpoint with https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost#wait-synchronous but now I need to send two different emails to two different addresses, at the same point in my program.

Seemed like the obvious way was to use the asynchronous method https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost#then-asynchronous but I can't get this working with the post endpoint. Code below.

Or is there a better way? I wasn't sure how to make the synchronous code do two separate requests one after the other.

```
$promise1 = $sparky->transmissions->post([
            'content' => [
                'from' => ['name' => 'My Service', 'email' => 'noreply@myservice.com'],
                'subject' => 'Booking Confirmation',
                'html' => $html,
                ],
            'recipients' => [['address' => ['email' => 'myemail@gmail.com']]],
            'options' => ['open_tracking' => false, 'click_tracking' => false]
            ]);

      $promise1->then(
        function ($response) // Success callback
            {
            echo('success promise 1');
            },
        function (Exception $e) // Failure callback
            {
            dump($e->getCode()."<br>".$e->getMessage());
            }
        );

$promise2 = $sparky->transmissions->post([
           'content' => [
               'from' => ['name' => 'My Service', 'email' => 'noreply@myservice.com'],
               'subject' => 'Another Email',
               'html' => $html,
               ],
           'recipients' => [['address' => ['email' => 'anotheremail@gmail.com']]],
           'options' => ['open_tracking' => false, 'click_tracking' => false]
           ]);

      $promise2->then(
       function ($response) // Success callback
           {
           echo('success promise 2');
           },
       function (Exception $e) // Failure callback
           {
           dump($e->getCode()."<br>".$e->getMessage());
           }
       );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined handlers for promise fulfillment and rejection.
But the promise requires to be fulfilled or rejected to invoke the handlers.

Since you're waiting for response from SparkPost, you need to `wait()` on the promise object.

`$promise1->wait();
 $promise2->wait();`

Read last line in Then (Asynchronous) Section of [SparkPost Reference](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost#then-asynchronous).

Also, if you're planning for multiple promises then you may use `\GuzzleHttp\Promise\all()` to combine all promises ( as suggested in second last line of same section )